# Why does Google Analytics show such a high percentage of traffic from Facebook as new users?

Tags: google-analytics

I am a UX designer, and one of my clients had some questions for me about Google Analytics.  His organization has a Facebook page and uses some paid Facebook advertising.  The comments on many of his Facebook posts (which promote his new blog articles) come from his site's regular readers.

Using a time scale in the past 30 days, Google Analytics is showing about 72% new users for his site.  In the same time period, about 65% of his traffic from Facebook is new users.  (If I shorten the time period to just yesterday, it's about 45% from Facebook and 63% from all sources.)  Since he expects most of his audience is regular readers, he would like to know: why would Google Analytics be showing so much of his audience as new?

I told him that it's likely to be happening because of some combination of users using private browsing / Do Not Track and cookies not persisting between sessions.  But we would like to know if there are any other factors.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the audience is. Europe has more stringent tracking laws, making it harder to count recurring users.

If users are searching in private browsing then they will also be counted as new users.

Also there might be a difference if someone is on the phone. It's possible that Facebook's in app web browser deletes cookies afterward. This could then have the same effect as incognito browsing.

Test this theory by just looking at the recurring users in America on the desktop.